# python server stub generated from swagger-codegen is simply not working locally

Tags: python, swagger

I generated python server stub from swagger-codegen at [swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/) online, and I want to run generated python server stub locally but it is not working and endpoint gave me `Not Found` error. I looked into swagger community, and not find single piece of issue related to this. Basically, I used openapi spec in `yaml` file to generate python server stub, but generated server stub can't be run locally. I don't know what is going on. Is there anyone experienced with this issue? what's the right way to generate python server stub from swagger-codegen which can be run and test locally? any idea?

**openapi spec file**

here is how yaml file begins:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: api
  description: test api
  contact:
    name: python server
    url: /api/v1/
    email: info@gmail.com
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: /api/v1/
  description: SwaggerHub API Auto Mocking
- url: /api/v1/
  description: IMM AWS Server 1
```

I generated python server stub by using this yaml file but generated python server stub is not working and can't run locally from python console/cmd. any idea to make this work? any possible thought?

**update**

here is what I tried:

```
    venv) C:\Users\kim\photoalbum_api>python -m swagger_server
The swagger_ui directory could not be found.
    Please install connexion with extra install: pip install connexion[swagger-ui]
    or provide the path to your local installation by passing swagger_path=<your path>

The swagger_ui directory could not be found.
    Please install connexion with extra install: pip install connexion[swagger-ui]
    or provide the path to your local installation by passing swagger_path=<your path>

 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

so I did `pip install connexion[swagger-ui]` and try to run it locally, but endpoint always gave me this:

[image]

for reproducible purpose, I also tested this [openapi spec file](https://github.com/michaelawyu/api_tutorial/blob/master/openapi/photo_album/openapi.yaml) to generate python server stub but it is not working as well. why? any idea to make this work? thanks

**new update**:

even I tried with `http://localhost:8080/`, endpoint always give me this:

```
(venv) C:\Users\kim\photouser_api>python -m swagger_server
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 198-543-983
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2020 12:13:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2020 12:14:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2020 12:14:05] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2020 12:14:10] "GET /api/v1 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2020 12:14:14] "GET /api/v1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2020 12:15:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Please expand on "python server stub is not working"

Comment: @rdas Hi, I updated my post with what I did. this problem is killing me. any idea?

Comment: Try the locahost url `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: @rdas I just quite desperate about this issue. Would you mind give a help? can we do zoom screen share shortly? thanks

Comment: @rdas I also tried many different ways but still not working, I pasted error messages above. any idea?

Comment: From the logs I can see that the requests are reaching your server now. The `/` path is giving you a 404 since the spec doesn't define any mapping for that. Try the `/users` path at `http://localhost:8080/users`

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add /api/v1/ to the url since it is added into the openapi spec? Plus do you have /users in your spec, and have operationID setup to target your python resource file?

Comment: @rdas how to define mapping then? if you any yaml file to generate python server stub, does it works for you?

Comment: @Paul Hi paul, I don't have user in spec and operationID. even I use [sample spec](https://github.com/michaelawyu/api_tutorial/blob/master/openapi/photo_album/openapi.yaml) and generate python server stub, still same error. any possible guess?

Comment: I just tried your repo and changed the url to /api/v1/ in the openapi.yaml. I had to change the connexion to 2.60 because I was getting werkzeug error. I ran the docker image and type http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ui to get to the swagger ui.

Comment: This is my output in the terminal when hitting the ui.

172.17.0.1 - - [17/May/2020 00:12:40] "GET /api/v1/openapi.json HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: @Paul can you share workable solution as an answer, like either posted on gist? thanks Paul :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214030/discussion-between-kim-and-paul).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it working in my machine, I cloned your repo [openapi.yaml](https://github.com/michaelawyu/api_tutorial/blob/master/openapi/photo_album/openapi.yaml). Then I modified the url to /api/v1/ in your openapi.yaml, and change the connexion to 2.6.0 in your [requirements.txt](https://github.com/michaelawyu/api_tutorial/blob/master/openapi/photo_album/codegen_server/requirements.txt). I created virtualenv and I followed the instructions in the [README.md](https://github.com/michaelawyu/api_tutorial/blob/master/openapi/photo_album/codegen_server/README.md) to install requirements.txt, and ran it. In the browser, I type http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ui and this should show the swagger ui. I also tried the docker build instruction and this also works.

Comment: where is tutorial for cookiecuttie? can you share some good resources for api development in python? thanks Paul

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api/ to learn about swagger, connexion, flask and sqlalchemy.